# Interaction between \parskip and tikzDevice affecting plot margins in .Rnw

Tags: r, plot, latex, knitr

I am knitting an `.Rnw` file and, unexpectedly, vertical space is lost from the bottom inner margin of my plots and added to the top outer margin.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

<<mwe-plot, dev="tikz", dev.args=list(bg="grey95")>>=
par(mar=rep(2,4), oma=rep(0,4))
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=21)
plot(x, sin(x), type="l")
box("inner")
@

\end{document}
```

`knit()` generates `mwe-plot-1.pdf`, which looks like this:

[image: plot with clipped margins], but what I expect is this:

[image: correct plot].

The issue is apparently due to an interaction between `\parskip` and tikzDevice, since it is corrected by setting `\parskip` to zero in the preamble or switching from `dev="tikz"` to the default `dev="pdf"`. While these are possible solutions, I am looking for a fix that doesn't require doing either.

Note that I tried adding `\setlength{\parskip}{0em}` immediately before the chunk (after `\begin{document}`) but this didn't affect the output.

Any hints are appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proximal problem is that the `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` statement is being included in the tikz .tex file, which is throwing off the spacing. The solution is to move it from your preamble into the body of your document, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
...
```

I figured this out by descending through the layers - first looking at the `.tex` output created by `knit` (before the LaTeX -> PDF conversion), then looking at `figure/mwe-plot-1.pdf` (and realizing, as you suggested, that the problem isn't with stuff that `knitr` puts in the LaTeX file, but with stuff that `tikzDevice` puts in the tikz-`.tex` file), then looking at `figure/mwe-plot-1.tex` and realizing that it had the `\parskip` statement embedded.  I looked around for a `tikzDevice` option that would override it, but then realized that it was probably only including stuff from the preamble ...